# How to reset MFA for my Office 365 account?

Tags: office365, authentication, two-factor-authentication

When logging in as an Office365 Admin, the user can change his own MFA settings including Authenticator App and Phone numbers (Under Additional security verification)

---

[image]

[image]

---

However, this option is not available for all users:

[image]

---

Is there an alternative way to reset my account MFA?

Comment: You should mark one of the answers as correct using the checkmark, to help future users know which answer worked, and give points to the person answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!

Visit https://aka.ms/mfasetup and continue by logging in with your Office365 account. Here you will be able to manage your info as needed:

[image]

Comment: Going to that link on my corporate account gives me `Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application '0000000c-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.`

Comment: that happens when you have multiple identities across multiple tenants and you are already connected with some in the same session. Try to use Incognito mode in your browser and connect with the correct credentials

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, https://aka.ms/mfasetup can be used to reset or update your MFA methods.

Administrators can also reset another user's MFA through https://portal.azure.com 
Then selecting **Azure Active Directory** -> **Users** -> Select the User -> **Authentication Methods**

There you can set up some types of authentication methods, require them to re-register, and reset their password as well.

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! FYI, I had to do the https://portal.azure.com steps first to revoke MFA sessions, and require re-registration of MFA, after which the user goes to https://aka.ms/mfasetup to re-setup MFA with their Microsoft Authenticator app or other option